# URL Definition in jQuery Data Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following HTML in a jQuery Data Template:

```
<a class="comment" style = "text-decoration:underline" href="ItemTitle/${Application.ApplicationId}/${Application.ApplicationName}/${DomainObjectId}/${DomainObjectPropertyNameFormatted}">${DomainObjectPropertyValue}</a>
```

As is above the template gets rendered on the ItemTitle view and produces a URL that appends all the URL elements to it. If I add a "/" before "ItemTitle" it goes to the root IIS website. I cannot use a html helper like Html.ActionLink because the template is only rendered after the page has loaded.

How can I get it to navigate to the correct URL?

Comment: Why dont you use a full URL instead of relative urls?

Comment: How would I use full URLs from a dev machine and a production machine? On dev you might have http://[some ip]/[path]/ItemTitle vs production that uses http://[domainname]/ItemTitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a variable with the dev url in it.

For example:

```
$FullURL = 'http://[some ip]/[path]';
```

And include it in your a href's like: href="<%=FullURL%>/ItemTitle/${Application.ApplicationId}.. etc".

When you change from development to production, simple change the $FullURL variable.